# 'If' Condition going wrong

Tags: php

Here, I am checking condition if `$type="register"` then it should not go in `if` condition as I did it like below but it goes wrong.

Here I am passing `$type="register"` but it is going in `if` condition and echoing `1`.

```
if((isset($type)) && (($type != "register") || ($type != "document_approved") || ($type != "document_rejection")))
{
    echo 1;
}
else
{
    echo 2;
}
```

But if I check condition like below then it is **working fine** and echoing `2`.

```
if((isset($type)) && ($type != "register"))
{
    echo 1;
}
else
{
    echo 2;
}
```

Am I going wrong anything? Thanks.

Comment: well, this condition `($type != "document_approved")` is true, making the whole condition true, so...

Comment: Change `||` to `&&`

Comment: You're checking if a value is not "x" OR it is not "y". This will always be true. It can't be both.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca : But `$type` is passing one at a time.

Comment: What do you mean? your condition is `a && (b || c || d)`. `c` is true (because `$type` is "register", so it is not "document_approved"), and so is `d`, making the condition `true && ( false || true || true )`, that is `true && true`, which is `true`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca : Ohh, I got your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You if condition contains

```
(($type != "register") || ($type != "document_approved") || ($type != "document_rejection"))
```

This will evaluate to true when atleast one condition is matched.

Since `$type = 'register'`, so `$type != "document_approved"` evalutates to true and it prints 1

Answer (score 1):

The logic is below

False ( it is equal to register)

True(it's not equal to document approved)

This check won't go any further.

Look at using !in_array($value, [register, document_approved,etc])

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this,

```
if((isset($type))
 {
   if(($type != "register") && ($type != "document_approved") && ($type != "document_rejection"))
         {
           echo 1;
         }
         else
         {
           echo 2;
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
if((isset($type)){
    if(($type != "register") || ($type != "document_approved") || ($type != "document_rejection"))
         {
           echo 1;
        }else{
           echo 2;
            }
   }
```

Comment: This will have the exact same effect as OP's version.